# I am sporadically getting this error : sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, sqlite

This happens with python 2.6.6, sqlite3. 
I have a db class that uses sqlite. Below is part of its init.

```
def _init_db(self):
"init the database tables and indices"
    print '\n'.join(DROP_TABLES[0:1])
    print '\n'.join(CREATE_TABLES[0:1])
    print '\n'.join(CREATE_INDEXES[0:1])
    print '\n'.join(CREATE_TRIGGERS[0:1])
    for query in DROP_TABLES:
       self.connection.execute(query)
#   self.connection.commit()
    for query in CREATE_TABLES:
       self.connection.execute(query)
#   self.connection.commit()        
    for query in CREATE_INDEXES:
       self.connection.execute(query)
#   self.connection.commit()
    for query in CREATE_TRIGGERS:
       self.connection.execute(query)            
    self.connection.commit()
```

Here is a printout of the queries. (its not very important in my opinion, here for completeness)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS graph_T 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS graph_T
(v1 int,
v2 int,
step_start int,
step_end int DEFAULT 2147483647,
value int DEFAULT 1,
path_kind int DEFAULT 0,
path_id long,
partial_path_id long) 

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idxgraph_T
          ON graph_T(v1,v2)

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS trig_graph_T_path_id
AFTER INSERT ON graph_T
BEGIN
UPDATE graph_T SET 
path_id = (10000 * 10000 * max(new.v1, new.v2) + 
    10000 * min(new.v1, new.v2) + 0 ) ,
partial_path_id = 10000 * 10000 * max(new.v1, new.v2) + 
    10000 * min(new.v1, new.v2)
WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
END;
```

I get sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file on one of the self.connection.execute lines. sometimes the third or fourth (it happens also in other places in my program).

I work on windows. I am not sure why this is happening and what i am doing wrong. 
Would appreciate any suggestions.

**More Information (due to questions asked):** 
- I am not using concurrent access. no threads or anything of that sort.

**edit- More info**: i have added a timed retry on all of the connection.execute lines and it usually fails once or twice, and then works. I am guessing that maybe the data wasnt *actually* written to disk when the execute command returns.

Answer (score 3):

My intuition tells me there's got to be something suspicious going on in the filesystem, not in the software.  Maybe one of these:

- a backup script is moving/renaming the file or a parent folder temporarily
- the filesystem appears "local" but is really a SAN and there is some intermittent problem with it
- other filesystem-oriented kernel modules, such as transparent encryption, is interfering with SQLite system calls
- Intrusion Detection Software is interfering with SQLite system calls
- another user is opening the file for read without your knowledge
- it's a virus `:-)`

Comment: I am not sure any of those options are very likely, but maybe i am wrong. Do you know if these things are plausible for a simple home windows 7? It would be nice if sqlite could have some retry mechanism build in or something. In any case, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is not good with concurrent access. If you have multiple threads or processes accessing the same database file, you will run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The concurrent access answer helped me solve my issue. My solution was essentially to revert back to a previous un-corrupted db file from before concurrent access occurred (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729827/3869714).