# django call_command syncdb failed: unable to open database file

Tags: database, django

I want to add some python codes after syncdb, so I decide to write a `build.py` which does everything including syncdb.

I write something in `build.py` as:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
```

But when I run `build.py`, it said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/csimstu/PycharmProjects/TeenHope/TeenHope/build.py", line 5, in <module>
    call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 161, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 56, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self._sqlite_create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in _sqlite_create_connection
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I've tried ./manage.py syncdb and use call_command in interactive shell mode, and both ways worked perfectly okay. How could it be?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636970/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file

Comment: No, not likely. It works fine in interactive shell. Maybe I just have to figure out the what ./manage.py shell command import.

Comment: Or give all the permissions to the folder maybe can be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database file isn't found that's probably because you didn't use a full path in your settings.

```
import os
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "relative_path_here", "database.db")),
```

Out of topic: I'd recommend to use Fabric for this kind of commands.

Comment: I've said that it works fine using syncdb. So I don't think it's the problem of full path.

Comment: OK but did you try? You've got nothing to lose making it absolute ! Another one, did you try to change the rights on that file and parent directory?

Comment: Sorry buddies, it's my own fault. I defined something in settings.py like `PROJECT_PATH = os.getcwd()`. But when running `build.py`, `PROJECT_PATH` is set to the current working directory, not the path of the project. By changing that to what you suggested, it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: NW, yes make sense, that's what getcwd does :)