# python unable to write to sqlite3 db from command line

Tags: python, command-line, sqlite

I have a python script that reads the temp froma ds18b20 sensor and writes it to a sqlite3 db located in the same directory. The section of code that writes to the database looks like this:

```
def write_DB(devID, devNAME, temp):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('templog.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()

    curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values((?),(?), datetime('now'), (?))", (devID, devNAME, temp))

    conn.commit()
```

When run from idle3 it runs fine, but when run from the command line, or cron, this is the output:

```
 ~/python/HydroMon $ /usr/bin/python /home/pi/python/HydroMon/ds18b20_scanner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/python/HydroMon/ds18b20_scanner.py", line 102, in <module>
  scan_dev()
 File "/home/pi/python/HydroMon/ds18b20_scanner.py", line 69, in scan_dev
  write_DB(file, dev, temp)
 File "/home/pi/python/HydroMon/ds18b20_scanner.py", line 49, in write_DB
  curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values((?),(?), datetime('now'), (?))", (devID, devNAME, temp))
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Any idea why this won't run from the command line? All the permissions are correct.

EDIT: I added this to write_db()

```
global basedir
db_file = basedir + '/templog.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
```

This no longer produces and error. This is the basedir assignment  function to open and read a conf file, which now causes an error. I have tried with python and python3.

```
#Configuratio Directory
fullpath = sys.argv[0]
basedir = os.path.dirname(fullpath)
confdir = basedir + "/conf"

#Variable to check if scan was good
reading = 0
def get_dev_name(devID):
    global confdir
    devName = 'NONE'
    #open conf file
    conf = confdir + '/devname.conf'
    print(conf)
    cfile = open(conf,mode='r')
```

When run from idle3 the result is:
    /home/pi/python/HydroMon/conf/devname.conf

When run from the command line:

```
~/python/HydroMon $ sudo python3 ds18b20_scanner.py 
/conf/devname.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "ds18b20_scanner.py", line 105, in <module>
  scan_dev()
 File "ds18b20_scanner.py", line 70, in scan_dev
  dev = get_dev_name(file)
 File "ds18b20_scanner.py", line 27, in get_dev_name
  cfile = open(conf,mode='r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/conf/devname.conf'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sqlite3, OperationalError: unable to open database file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636970/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I really don't think this is a duplicate of that. The problem here is simply that the OP is computing an invalid path to the database file. It has nothing to do with sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run it from the command line, try printing out `sys.argv[0]`. You may be surprised to see that it is `ds18b20_scanner.py`, which makes the dirname an empty string.

Perhaps you want to use `__file__` rather than `sys.argv[0]`, if you're trying to write to the same location as the script.

Comment: __file__ did not work for me, but using 

    fullpath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    basedir =  os.path.dirname(fullpath)

did the trick. Thanks!