# What does an 'r' represent before a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to understand why do we use a r before a path name in python such as

```
dirname = r'C:\temp\parts'
```

Answer (score 181):

`r` means the string will be treated as **raw string**.

See the official [Python 2 Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) about "String literals":

> When an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, a character following a
> backslash is included in the string without change, and *all
> backslashes are left in the string*. For example, the string literal
> `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `'n'`.
> String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash
> remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal
> consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is
> not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd
> number of backslashes). Specifically, *a raw string cannot end in a
> single backslash* (since the backslash would escape the following quote
> character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is
> interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, *not* as a
> line continuation.

Comment: has this anything to do with regex?

Comment: @Abdel No the `r` references *raw*, not *regex*

Comment: @Abdel & @Salem However `r`-prefixed raw strings are preferred for regex patterns because then one does not need to double-escape backslashes, e.g. `r'\d+'` is equivalent to `'\\d+'`, but more similar to the raw regex pattern they both contain: `\d+`.