# re find date in string

Tags: python, string, findall

Can someone explain how to use re.find all to separate only dates from the following strings? When the date can be either of the format- 1.1.2001 or 11.11.2001. There is volatile number of digits in the string representing days and months-

```
import re 
str = "This is my date: 1.1.2001 fooo bla bla bla"
str2 = "This is my date: 11.11.2001 bla bla foo bla"
```

I know i should use re.findall(pattern, string) but to be honest I am completely confused about those patterns. I don't know how to assemble the pattern to fit in my case.

I have found something like this but I absolutely don't know why there is the r letter before the pattern ... \ means start of string? d means digit? and number in {} means how many?

```
match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', text)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should have a look at [the doc for re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and you can have a look at https://regex101.com/ to test regular expressions interactively.

Comment: This is just perfect ... this online regular expression tester! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `r` prefix to the strings tells the Python Interpreter it is a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which essentially means backslashes `\` are no longer treated as escape characters and are literal backslashes.  For `re` module it's useful because backslashes are used a lot, so to avoid a lot of `\\` (escaping the backslash) most would use a raw string instead.

What you're looking for is this:

```
match = re.search(r'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}', text)
```

The `{}` tells regex how many occurrences of the preceding set you wanted.  `{1,2}` means a minimum of 1 and a maxmium of 2 `\d`, and `{4}` means an exact match of 4 occurrences.

Note that the `.` is also escaped by `\.`, since in regex `.` means *any character*, but in this case you are looking for the literal `.` so you escape it to tell regex to look for the literal character.

See this for more explanation: https://regex101.com/r/v2QScR/1

Comment: Thanks friend! You taught me a lot! and your solution is working!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two distinct processes happening in this code.

1. When you enter some text `"..."` it first needs to be interpreted by the python interpreter at runtime
2. Then the python interpreter passes the result `result("...")` to its own internal regex interpreter

In order to match a special character like a digit, python's internal regex interpreter supports special characters like `\d`. So the regex interpreter is expecting to get `\d`. Unfortunately, the character `\` is also an escape character for the python interpreter in the first step of the process.

In order to avoid the python interpreter eating up `\` and only passing `d` to the regex interpreter. We put `r"..."` in front of our strings to indicate a "raw string" - which means "Hey python interpreter, don't touch my `\` characters!". This will result in the correct special characters being passed through.

Comment: Many thanks. All of you guys helped me and i have learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Use `r` is a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729045/what-does-an-r-represent-before-a-string-in-python) which means it will not get escaped or altered by `\` in a string

Python describes `\` as this:

> Either escapes special characters (permitting you to match characters like '*', '?', and so forth), or signals a special sequence;

Basically meaning that if you use a character that would normally be a special character to regex it ignores this.

`{}` are used for repetitions:

> Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as few repetitions as possible. This is the non-greedy version of the previous qualifier. For example, on the 6-character string 'aaaaaa', a{3,5} will match 5 'a' characters, while a{3,5}? will only match 3 characters.

Meaning that it will repeat the previous character the number you specified in `{}`

`\d` is a special character that matches any digit from 0 to 9.

I highly recommend you [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

`re.findall()` returns a list of everything it matches using that regex.

Comment: Many thanks. All of you guys helped me and i have learned something new.