# "\n" not working in python when reading files

Tags: python

Let's say I have an example file named 'greetings.txt' with this in it

```
Hello\nThere
```

and this code

```
f = open("greetings.txt", "r")
readit = f.read()
print(readit)
```

But the output is

```
Hello\nThere
```

What do I do to make the output detect the "\n" and put Word "There" to the 2nd line?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(readit.replace(r'\n','\n'))
```

(When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729045/what-does-an-r-represent-before-a-string-in-python?lq=1))