# Basic issue with glob in python

Tags: python, glob

I'm really unexpert in python, so forgive my question if stupid.

I'm trying a simple script that operates on all the files in a folder.
However, I apparently can only access the folder recursively!

I explain. I have a folder, DATA, with subfolders for each day (of the form YYYY-MM-DD).

If I try

```
for filename in glob.glob('C:\Users\My username\Documents\DATA\2021-01-20\*'):
  print filename
```

I get no output.

However, if I try instead

```
for filename in glob.glob('C:\Users\My username\Documents\DATA\*\*'):
  print filename
```

the output is that expected:

```
C:\Users\My username\Documents\DATA\2021-01-20\210120_HOPG_sputteredTip0001.sxm
C:\Users\My username\Documents\DATA\2021-01-20\210120_HOPG_sputteredTip0002.sxm
...
```

I even tried different folder names (removing the dashes, using letters in the beginning, using only letters, using a shorter folder name) but the result is still the same.

What am I missing?

(BTW: I am on python 2.7, and it's because the program I need for the data is only compatible with python 2)

Comment: Replace the backslashes with forward slashes (or double them up to escape them: `C:\Users` becomes `C:\\Users`), backslashes are used to escape characters in strings

Comment: or try double \\

Comment: or mark the string a raw, eg r""

Comment: Thanks, all suggestions actually work! Though using r is the best, no path manipulation so no errors and a reusable string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware when using backslashes in strings. In Python this means escaping characters. Try prepending your string with `r` like so:

```
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\My username\Documents\DATA\*'):
    # Do you business
```

**Edit:**
As @poomerang has pointed out a shorter answer has previously been provided as to what 'r' does in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729045/what-does-an-r-represent-before-a-string-in-python)

Official docs for Python string-literals: [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and for [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: That was it! I had completely forgotten about escape characters, but that fixes it. Thanks!
In case someone else is interested, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729045/what-does-an-r-represent-before-a-string-in-python) I found the explanation for the `r` prefix

Comment: @poomerang lovely. Glad to help :D. I've updated the answer with the link you provided and links to the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

Recursive file search is not possible with `glob` in Python 2.7. I.e. searching for files in a folder, its subfolders, sub-subfolders and so on.

You have two options:

- use `os.walk` (you might need to change your code's structure however)
- Use the backported `pathlib2` module from PyPI https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/ - which should include a `glob` function supporting the recursive search using `**` wildcard.