# Ignore \n character when iterate over a list in python

Tags: python, list, character

I have a list like that

```
mylist
['\nms-0/0/0\n', '\nms-0/1/0\n', '\nms-0/2/0\n']
```

and I want to use every literal value of the list in a way that  \n character is ignored:

Example:

```
for i in mylist:
     flows.xpath("//service-sfw-flow-count[interface-name=i]/flow-count//text()")
```

the value of "i" is not \nms-0/0/0\n but ms-0/0/0 , so I wonder if there is an option to use the literal value of every element of the list.

I've tried repr(i), but I got extra characters

```
"'\\nms-0/0/0\\n'"
```

Any idea ?

Regards

Comment: `i.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: I want the value of i in the loop is \nms-0/0/0\n , I don't want to remove \n

Comment: replace does not modify original string. Use `i.replace` wherever you don't want `\n`s and just `i` where you do want them.

Comment: if `\n` is either at the start or end of the string you could use `str.strip('\n')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was an issue with the xpath expression

```
new.xpath("//service-sfw-flow-count[interface-name='" + i + "']/flow-count//text()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use

> i.replace('\n', '')

to replace that characters with an empty string.

For example.

```
for i in mylist:
     new_i = i.replace('\n', '')
     flows.xpath("//service-sfw-flow-count[interface-name=i]/flow-count//text()")
```

On the other hand, if the i deflows.xpath is your variable, it may be advisable to make the following modification.

```
for i in mylist:
     new_i = i.replace('\n', '')
     flows.xpath(f"//service-sfw-flow-count[interface-name={new_i}]/flow-count//text()")
```

Comment: Now you can use new_i or i depending on whether or not you want to use /n

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the problem , it was an issue with the xpath expression.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
mylist = [r'\nms-0/0/0\n', r'\nms-0/1/0\n', r'\nms-0/2/0\n']
print(mylist)
```

[find more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729045/what-does-an-r-represent-before-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).