# python sqlite3 connection path with spaces

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to connect with a full path but I get this problem

```
>>> path = "/home/astro/Fun LAB/DBlist"
>>> db = sql.connect(path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
>>>
```

i 've also tried this

```
>>> path = "/home/astro/Fun\ LAB/DBlist"
>>> db = sql.connect(path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
>>>
```

I know it's because of the whitespace cause I've tried this and it works

```
>>> path = "/home/astro/DBlist"
>>> db = sql.connect(path)
>>>
```

so is there is an easy way to escape the whitespaces in the path or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it is a permission issue. Do you have write and execute permission on the `Fun LAB` directory?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637055/168377

Comment: @unutbu I also tried to run the script from the same folder like this
              " ~/Fun Lab $ python3
               Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
               [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
               Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more              information.
                >>> import sqlite3 as sql
                >>> path = "DBlist"
                >>> db = sql.connect(path)
                >>> "

so that's why I don't think it's a permission problem

Comment: @emil.p.stanchev I've already seen this  before asking but I couldn't find where does it help me

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [uri style approach](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) - it worked for me in getting past connection issues due to spaces in file paths with sqlite3:

- Escaping the spaces with %20
- prefixing the path with file:///

Examples:

- file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/fred/Desktop/data.db
  file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/fred/Desktop/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest naming files or folders **without spaces**. (*I don't think it's possible either*) Instead, **use dash or underscores**.

The next problem is to see where you're running your Python interpreter. If it's nested inside a directory and you're trying to create a path from the outside, then your link would raise an error.

```
>>> path = "/home/astro/Fun LAB/DBlist"
```

or

```
>>> path = "/home/astro/Fun\ LAB/DBlist"
```

or

```
>>> path = "/home/astro/DBlist"
```

wouldn't work if you run python inside these directories or from another.

**To correct this, try**:

```
>>> path = "../home/path/to/file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Having spaces is indeed a problem.
I would suggest bring a symlink and work with that:

```
!ln -sf '$path_to_db_file' .
db = sql.connect('db_file')
```