# unable to open database file for sqlite3 in my Flask app

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, apache2

I have a Flask app where I call `sqlite3.connect('database.db')`. This causes the error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`. This seems to work fine when testing on Windows but not on Debian.

My project is organized as so:

```
flaskapp.wsgi
flask_app
    __init__.py
    init_db.py
    database.db
```

`init_db.py` creates the database with a table and an entry for that table, running that works just fine. `__init__.py` has the flask app itself with the following method inside it:

```py
def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn
```

The stacktrace ends at the first line of this method with the error previously mentioned. For more context the app works when I test it out with the development server on Windows 10. But not on my webserver which is running Debian and Apache2.

I expect it to simply connect and do all the database stuff I want to do. I suspect it has something to do with Apache2 having some default behavior I didn't expect in relation to Flask. It doesn't appear to be an issue with file permissions, I tried everything that was recommended in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637055/21932305 but I still have the error.

Comment: Have you tried putting `./database.db` as the path? And in your debian environment what command are you invoking to start flask app and from which folder??

Comment: @Kartoos I tried that, same error. I use `systemctl start apache2` to start it from `/var/www/flask_app/flask_app`

Comment: I have a feeling that your relative path is getting messed up when you are running on Apache. Can you try to print `here` variable in your code: `here = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: Most likely your app does not have permission to write into the app's current working directory.

Comment: @JohnHanley `flask_app` and `database.db` have `www-data` as their owners which according to the list of processes is what is running Apache2

Comment: @Kartoos The output of that is `/var/www/flask_app/flask_app` the directory `__init__.py` is sitting in. I tried `./flask_app/database.db` too and still no luck.

Comment: Using the full path seems to work. I don't like that solution much but it'll do I suppose!

Comment: You should never allow writing to the same directory as your source code. That is one way that sites are breached. Your database should be stored in a directory outside of the site with correct ownership and permissions.